# Reshape the array along the reverse dimensions

Tags: arrays, matlab

```
>> A = [ 1 2 3 3 4 5 5 6 7 7 8 9 ];
>>
>> B = reshape(A, 2, 2, 3)

B(:,:,1) =

     1     3
     2     3


B(:,:,2) =

     4     5
     5     6


B(:,:,3) =

     7     8
     7     9
```

Since `reshape` can only change the size of the given array in the way of preserving the linear indices, however I would like to reshape the array along the reverse dimensions.

For example, convert `A` into

```
>> C = reverse-reshape(A, 2, 2, 3)  % not required to be only one function

C(:,:,1) =

     1     3
     5     7

C(:,:,2) =

     2     4
     6     8

C(:,:,3) =

     3     5
     7     9
```

Is there any better method than writing loops and fill numbers one by one in version R2017b?

Comment: Are you looking to do this for any number of dimensions, or specifically 3?

Comment: @rayryeng I think I don't need a general method for every size of array. Specifically dim = 3 may be enough. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would first `reshape` with the dimensions in reverse order, then swap the first and third dimensions with [`permute`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) to reorder the elements so that they are populated in reverse order:

```
>> B = permute(reshape(A, 3, 2, 2), [3 2 1])

B(:,:,1) =

     1     3
     5     7


B(:,:,2) =

     2     4
     6     8


B(:,:,3) =

     3     5
     7     9
```

To do this in general independent of the matrix dimensions and assuming it is a 3D matrix, declare an array called `dims` that contains the output desired matrix size, reverse the elements and supply this into `reshape`:

```
dims = [2 2 3];
B = permute(reshape(A, fliplr(dims)), [3 2 1]);
```

[`fliplr`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fliplr.html) reverses the elements in a matrix horizontally.